# Error (1062, "Duplicate entry '4' for key 'user_id'") on django loaddata

Tags: python, mysql, django

I just deleted my localhost database due to export my production website database and then import it to my lcoal db

I used this command to dump db:

> ./manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes --exclude auth.permission
> --exclude sessions --indent 2 > dump.json

and then on my localhost:

> ./manage.py loaddata dump.json

but I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 72, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 114, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 181, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 223, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1392, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/home/mehdi/python/projects/FollowBotWebsite/v1.2.2/dump.json': Could not load users.Profile(pk=1): (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")
```

I searched a lot but all soloutions were about permissions or auth, not my own models.

Comment: Your question was on a different topic, but your command `./manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes --exclude auth.permission --exclude sessions --indent 2 > dump.json` has solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used signals to make a profile for each user on creation,
solved this problem with addign `not raw`  to my signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, raw=False, **kwargs):
    if created and not raw:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        print('Profile Created')
```